# using assert_that on vectors throws error

Tags: r, assert

I am trying to check that each value in a vector is less than or equal to 2. assert_that seems to have an issue with this (possibly due to my lack of understanding). Can someone tell me whats wrong here?

```
> require(assertthat)
> x<-c(1,2,1.5)
> assert_that(x<=2) #should return true
Error: assert_that: assertion has length greater than 1
> y<-c(1,2,1.5,3,3)
> assert_that(y<=2) #should return false
Error: assert_that: assertion has length greater than 1
> stopifnot(x<=2)
```

Comment: I was missing the all() in my case I needed all(y<=2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just saying

```
assert_that(y<=2)
```

is ambiguous. Do you want *all* `y<=2`? Do you want *at least one* `y<=2`? You can use `assert_that(all(y<=2))` or `assert_that(any(y<=2))` respectively to collapse down to a single assertion.